# Loop through undetermined number of nested arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is parsing data via JSON. The JSON contains nested arrays and the number of nested arrays varies between JSON files.

What would be the best way to loop through all of these nested arrays with Objective C? Should I use a recursive function, recursive block or is there an enumeration method that can achieve this goal?

Here is a simple diagram of how the data is represented in the JSON:

```
[
string,
string,
    array[string,
          array[string
               ],
          string
         ],
string
]
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend for this kind of work [underscorem](http://underscorem.org/), a very nice library that makes really easy deal with this kind of tasks.
In your case once you parsed the json into an array

```
//You will need to import Underscore.h 
#import "Underscore.h"

//That would look like myArray
NSArray *myArray = @[@"1somestring",@"2somestring",@[@"3anotherstring",@[@"4thirdLevelString",@"5string"],@"6string"],@"7string"];
NSArray *flattenArray = Underscore.flatten(myArray);
NSLog(@"flattenArray: %@",flattenArray);
```

flattenArray will contain this:

```
@[@"1somestring",@"2somestring",@"3anotherstring",@"4thirdLevelString",@"5string",@"6string",@"7string"]
```

and will give you an output like this:

```
flattenArray: (
1somestring,
2somestring,
3anotherstring,
4thirdLevelString,
5string,
6string,
7string
```

)

Comment: This library looks incredibly helpful, thank you for sharing.